# String-based linked list in C produces segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, pointers, linked-list

```
----------
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char *val;
    struct node *next;
};

void add_to_list(struct node **, char *);
void list_all_elements(struct node *);

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{

    char *val;
    struct node *head = NULL;

    do  {

        scanf("%s",val);
        add_to_list(&head, val);

    }
    while(val[0] != '\\');

    list_all_elements(head);
}

void add_to_list(struct node **head, char *val) 
{
    //This produces a segfault
    struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof *temp);

    //EDIT - Fixed as per comments
    temp->val = malloc(strlen(val) + 1);

    strcpy(temp->val, val);
    temp->next = NULL;

    if(head!=NULL)
        temp->next = *head;

    *head = temp;

}

void list_all_elements(struct node *head)   
{

    while(head!=NULL)   {

        printf("%s\n",head->val);
        head = head->next;
    }
}
```

So this is what I compiled to implement a linked list. Now, for some reason malloc'ing the produces a segmentation fault.

To be sure, I replaced char * with a char [] and the code runs just fine. Is the malloc faulting due to this or is there some trivial error I can't seem to find?

Comment: head is not going to be null, you should check *head, but this is not going to change anything it means that every time you assign temp->next = *head; that is the right thing to do, you don't need the if at all (and the temp->next = NULL)

Comment: 1) `char *val;` --> `char val[MAX_STRING_SIZE];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not allocate memory that would be pointed to by variable `val` and where you are going to read a string.

```
char *val;

//... 

do  {

    scanf("%s",val);
    add_to_list(&head, val);

}
```

Variable val was not initialized so the program has undefined behaviour.

And function `add_to_list` is invalid. For example `sizeof(val)` has always the same value that is equal to the size of the pointer to char. It does not yield the size of a string pointed to by this pointer. Instead of the operator `sizeof` you shall use function `strlen`

The function could be written like

```
void add_to_list( struct node **head, const char *val ) 
{
    struct node *temp = malloc( sizeof *temp );

    size_t n = strlen( val );

    temp->val = malloc( n + 1 );
    strcpy( temp->val, val );

    temp->next = *head;

    *head = temp;
}
```

Comment: This! Thank you! That was naive of me!

Comment: But shouldn't scanf throw a fault there?

Comment: @user3576305 The program has undefined behaviour so it is not predictable what will occur.

Comment: @user3576305 Also do not forget to free all allocated memory.

Comment: Yes yes. I was just showing the relevant code here.

Answer (score 2):

You did not allocate the val in the main

```
char *val;
...
scanf("%s",val);
```

but here `val` is not allocated, when you do the scanf is going to sigsegv

Answer (score 1):

```
temp->val = malloc(sizeof(val));
```

Change `sizeof(val)` to `strlen(val)+1`.

Comment: strlen()+1 or you will have no space to write the \0

Comment: @user3576305: Change `sizeof *temp` to `sizeof struct node`.  You are dereferencing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @Kevin No, that's a legal way to operate with sizeof. Nothing wrong with that.